# Сделать фон во всю ширину за контейнером

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

При масштабировании страницы фон липнет к одному краю и уезжает. Это нормально? Нужно будет адаптировать под такой размер или можно растягивать картинку в нормальном положении?

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.why-us-background {
    background: url("picture.png") no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1050px;
    background-position: 0 150px;
}


.why-us-container {
    padding-top: 60px;
    background: #181819;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="why-us-background">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="why-us-container">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании background-size:cover картинка срезается снизу. как уметить всю? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> При использовании background-size:cover картинка срезается снизу. как уметить всю?

Вот пример того что картинка показывается на весь контейнер...

Свои свойства я выделил комментарием. Добавил бордер для понимания границ контейнера.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.why-us-background {
  background: url("https://1001puzzle.ru/upload/iblock/cb8/cb8ee635c1c5daccd8b0a671b19d860a.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1050px;
  background-position: 0 150px;
  /* добавил */
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border: 5px dotted red;
}

.why-us-container {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background: #181819;
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="why-us-background">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="why-us-container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется изображение чёрное должно было быть выше контейнера? То есть выходить за контейнер?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, какой исходный `css` был дан - такой я и использовал... `background-position` я так же не трогал... Т.ч. ждем ТСа, может он прольет свет на твой вопрос. И опять же - у тебя есть уникальный шанс разместить тут свой вариант ответа. ;)

Comment: Я хотел разместить, но передумал, так как мозги устали, не смог сделать то, о чем написал тебе выше).

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, надеюсь что в том нет моей вины... :)

Comment: Это получился паралакс. Мне нужно чтобы фон был на весь экран, контейнер 1500px. 
Фон должен быть в полный размер и должен быть больше по высоте, чем контейнер. Конкретнее - второе фото.

Comment: @fropid, фон контейнера ну никак не сможет быть больше чем сам контейнер...

Comment: "`Параллакс` - это смещение или разница в видимом положении объекта". Фоновая картинка блока больше самого блока - это не паралакс. Это что-то из области фантастики.